# webpack, why 'eval' is described as faster at 'rebuild'

Tags: performance, webpack, eval, source-maps, rebuild

`eval` is one of the types of **webpack** source-map. As the official doc says,

> **eval** - Each module is executed with `eval()` and `//@ sourceURL`. This is pretty fast. The main disadvantage is that it doesn't display line numbers correctly since it gets mapped to transpiled code instead of the original code.

I don't quite understand, why it's fast in this way?